# After inserting XML into SQL table and parsing it getting "???" instead of text

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to get the actual text instead of `???` result .
using sql - mssql 2005

I already tried collation and it didn't work

```
truncate table EPGXML    
INSERT  INTO EPGXML
        ( Data        
        )
        SELECT  CONVERT(XML,BulkColumn,2)
        FROM    OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\test\test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) O;

DECLARE @Data XML;
SELECT @Data = Data FROM EPGXML ;

select distinct filenode.value('category[1]', 'VARCHAR(300)')
FROM    @Data.nodes('tv/programme ') files ( filenode )
where filenode.value('category[1]', 'VARCHAR(300)') is not null
```

Comment: character set issue? can't really help you since you haven't mentioned WHAT database this is.

Comment: Added a `sql-server` tag, based on the `OPENROWSET` and `DECLARE @Data XML` clues. If this is **not** what you're using - please fix the tag! You should **always** include the concrete database (and the version you're using!) when asking a database-related question here on SO !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to read unicode text?  Use `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` for unicode support.